# How to make noise more square-like?

Tags: graph-editor

I have noise as an F-modifier in the graph editor on a bone animation. However, I want it to be more sudden and make the curve more like a square-wave than sinusoidal. When I look at the options though, I only see a smoothing key, not a sharpening key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've set up your noise curve, simply add a *Stepped Interpolation* modifier to make it blockish. Use the *Step Size* parameter to adjust the "definition".

[image]

Comment: Thanks! <insert 8 more characters because of stupid rule>